# Field 'id' expected a number but got 'create'

Tags: python, django

This a my django project code, i have an error in this project please help me to solve this error. so i can run my project.

**Question **
Exception Value:
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'create'

Traceback (most recent call last):

C:\Users\acer\Desktop\Air\air_site\todo\views.py, line 15, in todo_details
15.     todo = Todo.objects.get(id=id)

**Code**

**views.py**

```
def todo_details(request, id):
    todo = Todo.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {
        "todo": todo
    }
    return render(request, "todo/todo_details.html", context)
def todo_create(request):
    todo = Todo.objects.get(id=id)
    form =TodoForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "todo/todo_create.html", context)
```

**0001_initial.py**

```
operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Todo',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ('due_date', models.DateField()),
        ],
    ),
]
```

**urls files is hear**

```
app_name = 'todos'
urlpatterns = [

    path("", views.todo_list),
    path('<id>/', views.todo_details),
    path('create/', views.todo_create),
    path('delete/', views.todo_delete),

    ]
```

**templates files are hear**
**todo_detail.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Todo Details</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
          Hello {{ request.user.username }}
      {% else %}
          Hello anonymous user
      {% endif %}

      The todo name is :- {{ todo.name }}
      The due  date is :- {{ todo.due_date }}


<h1>Hello</h1>


  </body>
</html>
```

**todo_create**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Todo Create</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h4>Create a todo</h4>
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" name="button">submit</button>



      </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please show your template where you are calling that view ?

Comment: provide full traceback

Comment: The problem is not the model... but the `urls`...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py try send the id into function;

```
def todo_create(request,id):
```

Answer (score 0):

in urls instead of this

```
path('create/', views.todo_create),
```

add this

```
path('create/<int:id>', views.todo_create),
```

in views

```
def todo_create(request):
```

to

```
def todo_create(request,id):
```